# reading one record from access in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

My requirement is to read Date column from access file and use one value to append it to a file name, so as to create file with date timestamp using the db value.

I am trying following approach but it gives me exception "No data exists for the row/column":

here's the code

```
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

        string dt  = "SELECT top 1 Date FROM Events";


        OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(dt, conn1);
        conn1.Open();
        OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

        string time_stmp = rdr.GetInt32(0).ToString();

        rdr.Close();
        conn1.Close();

        string path = text_dir + "\\" + time_stmp + "_" + "BWC_Ejournal.txt";
```

Comment: Does your query return anything?

Comment: Apologies it's so obvious, but have you confirmed your connections are working properly? Are they connecting to the correct db? Is there actually any data in the 'Events' table?

Comment: yes events table has data

Comment: And (again obvious, sorry!), this query returns data when you run it directly against your Access database?

Comment: yes it does, i just executed query against table returns 1 record

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to call the Read() method on the OleDbDataReader object before accessing its data.

E.g.

```
OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
string time_stmp = "";

if(rdr.Read())
{
    time_stmp = rdr.GetInt32(0).ToString();
}
else
{
    //handle no data situation here
}
```

This will also allow to handle a situation where no data is returned more gracefully too.

Answer (score 1):

`DATE` is a [reserved word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738) in ACE/Jet SQL. Try this instead:

```
string dt  = "SELECT TOP 1 [Date] FROM Events";
```

### Edit

On taking a closer look at your code I notice that you create the `OleDbCommand` object before the connection is opened. I've seen that cause problems as well. FWIW, the following code works for me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace oleDbTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var con = new OleDbConnection(
                        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                        @"Data Source=C:\__tmp\main.accdb;"))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(
                            "SELECT TOP 1 [Date] FROM [Events]", con))
                {
                    string time_stmp =  Convert.ToDateTime(cmd.ExecuteScalar()).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
                    Console.WriteLine(time_stmp.ToString());
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }
}
```